# Selecting rows as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 2 tables in database

`tblServices`:

```
serviceID    
serviceName
```

`tblDomains`:

```
domainID  
domainName  
Parent
```

Now I want to select

```
serviceID serviceName domainID domainName1 domainName2 domainName3 ...
```

i.e I want to select all the domainName as rows where parent == serviceName

Comment: So if somebody adds a row to one of the tables, you want one more column?

Comment: Don't handle this in `SQL`, let your application perform the `PIVOT`.

Answer (score -1):

***Simple Way To Use Pivot In SQL Query***
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

***One Example Here.***
[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: please don't simply post links, at least offer some explanation as to how this can be applied. if those links move or change, this answer will be useless.